# Changing background color of cells if a value is greater than or equal to

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm stuck at changing a color if a number is greater than zero in my `DataGrid`.
I tried `IValueConverter`, but can't really make it work. It only works if I already know the value in the `DataGrid`.
This is my XAML. The green color is the one I can make work
with the code below it. I tried to bind it with the `IValueConverter`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_ProductlistGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Loaded="form1_load">
       
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="30,9,12,6"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProduktID" Binding="{Binding Path=factProduct.ProductId}" Width="*"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Navn" Binding="{Binding Path= factProduct.Name}" Width="*"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mængde" Binding="{Binding Path =QauntityNeeded }" Width="*"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rigtige Mængde" Binding="{Binding Path =FoundQauntity }" Width="*"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mangel" Binding="{Binding Path = Missing}" Width="*"  IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" >
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Missing, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

This is my `IValueConverter`:

```
public class Greaterthan : IValueConverter
{
    
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int input = (int)value;
        if (input < 1)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your converter does not check if the value is greater than zero, but if it is smaller than one. You can simplify your converter and make it more powerful at the same time. Expect the *greater than* value as parameter for the converter. Although you can specify an `int` in XAML as a parameter, it is more readable to specify the value as a `string`, as you will below when using the converter. This converter parses the `string` value and parameter as `int` and returns whether the value is *greater than* the parameter as `bool`.

```
public class GreaterThanConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (!(value is string valueText) ||
          !(parameter is string parameterText) ||
          !int.TryParse(valueText, out var intValue) ||
          !int.TryParse(parameterText, out var intParameter))
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      return intValue > intParameter;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

In XAML you can use a `DataTrigger` with a binding to `Text` that uses the converter. If the converter returns `true` (meaning the value is greater than the parameter), a specific color is set.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Text" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
         </Trigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource GreaterThanConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
         </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

---

Make sure to instantiate the converter in any resource dictionary, e.g. on the `DataGrid`, otherwise you will get an error that the resource cannot be resolved.

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.Resources>
      <local:GreaterThanConverter x:Key="GreaterThanConverter"/>
   </DataGrid.Resources>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</DataGrid>
```

Also make sure that you defined the `local` namespace in the XAML file.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWpfApp.MyNamespace"
```

Comment: The resource "converter" could not be resolved 
got this a couple of times with the different stuff I tried implementing but cant really seems to find out why

Comment: @Gerken Of course, you have to create an instance of the converter in a resource dictionary first in order to use it. See the edit.

Comment: "The type 'GreaterThanConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built."

Am I missing something in the app.xaml or am I not supposed to write this in the xaml.cs in the view or am I missing something in the xml with the xmln = name something?
im not sure what to do

Comment: I fixed that mistake but "The tag 'GreaterThanConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

Comment: @Gerken Sorry, I forgot to specify the XAML namespace for the converter. See the update. Prefix the converter with a namespace and add a namespace declaration for the namespace where your converter resides.

Comment: <UserControl 
x:Class="MainUI.View.CaseProductListPageView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      Complain about the text above

Already tried these namespaces and it can find my Converter if I made a seperate class in the viewmodel but complains about the "xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MainUI.View" 
             xmlns:q="clr-namespace:MainUI.ViewModel"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:MainUI.ViewModel"
             >

Comment: Nevermind for some reason the mistake made itself go away 
thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

In your case it would be better to move the complete logic to pick the color to the converter. You should then remove all triggers and bind `DataGridCell.Background` directly to the current value of `Missing`.
You can also use `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` instead of the `EditStyle`.

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <IntegerToBrushConverter x:Key="IntegerToBrushConverter" />
  </DataGrid.Resources>

  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Missing}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <Setter Property="Background" 
                  Value="{Binding Missing, Converter={StaticResource IntegerToBrushConverter}}" />
        </Style>
      </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid>
```

**IntegerToBrushConverter.cs**

```
class IntegerToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    switch (value)
    {
      case int numericValue when numericValue == 0: return Brushes.LightGreen; 
      case int numericValue when numericValue > 0: return Brushes.Red; 
      case int numericValue when numericValue > 1 && numericValue < 5: return Brushes.Blue; 
      default: return Brushes.Yellow;
    }
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```